# Extract TIN mesh

Tags: qgis, python, tin, mesh

I have a shapefile that I convert into TIN. The result is following:

[image]

Now I want to extract a mesh based on this TIN to reach this:

[image]

However I do not need TIN itself, I need only to save the mesh. I'm trying to do it with this code:

```
def tin(self, grid_layer):
    try:
        params = {'CRS_OUTPUT': self.CRS,
                  'MESH_FORMAT': 0,
                  'OUTPUT_MESH': self.dest + os.sep + 'tin.2dm',
                  'SOURCE_DATA': [
                      {'source': grid_layer.name() + '.shp', 'type': 0,
                       'attributeIndex': grid_layer.fields().indexFromName(
                           'alt')}
                  ]}
        processing.run('native:tinmeshcreation', params)
        export_param = {
            'CRS_OUTPUT': self.CRS,
            'DATASET_GROUPS': [],
            'DATASET_TIME': {'type': 'static'},
            'INPUT': params['OUTPUT_MESH'],
            'OUTPUT': self.dest + os.sep + 'new.dxf',
            'VECTOR_OPTION': 0
        }
        processing.run('native:exportmeshfaces', export_param)
        self.update_progress()
    except Exception as ex:
        self.iface.messageBar().pushWarning('Ошибка cоздания поверхноcти', str(ex))
```

However, the *.dxf* file forms as empty. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it was an issue with mesh layer. It should be fixed with version last 3.22 and 3.28 version.